# setting of order of display <div> in HTML using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two `<div>` and I have difficulty ordering them. 
Please teach me and help me.

```
<div class="menubar">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="itmes"></li>
        <li class="itmes"></li>
        <li class="itmes"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="b_header">

</div>
```

This is the related CSS.

```
.menubar{
width: 110%;
background-color: #000000;
margin-top: 32px;
height: 35px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
margin-left: -20px;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;}

.b_header{
width: 110%;
background: url('./img/b_header.gif');
margin-left: -20px;
height: 15px;
position: inherit;
margin-top: 0px;}
```

I want and expect to see `<div class="b_header">` below the `<div class="b_header">` but it isn't.

What is the solution?

Comment: @sfshah I used % only for width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove

```
position:absolute;
```

and it will work. Absolute positioning will remove the menu from the flow of the page so the header div below it will effectively pretend like the menu is not there.

Alternatively (if you need `position:absolute`) you can force your header below the menu by giving the header a `margin-top:67px;`

Comment: No problem. Please mark this as the correct answer so this question can be closed

Answer (score 0):

Your vertical-align of menubar is middle so I suspect that b_header is being put above it? Try vertical-align: top;